# Problem Running VS 2019 Web App: Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: .net, iis-express, visual-studio-2019

I am working on a .NET C# Server for an iOS/Android app. The software was created by an offshore team and it is my job to work and debug problems with it. Problem is every time I run this application through IIS Express in VS Community 2019, I get the following error in Microsoft Edge. Where do I go from here to pinpoint the issue?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: What kind of server? If you cannot provide a reproducible sample or any more useful info, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Are you getting this error in Microsoft Edge only? How about other browsers?

Comment: Its an API running .NetFramework 4.7.1. IIS Express automatically opens a Microsoft Edge Browser window and shows that error message when I click the button labeled IIS Express(Microsoft Edge) with the green arrow

Comment: Just tried with Crome, same error

Comment: Check to see if there is a Route prefix, given it's an API it most probably be `api` that is why you get a `404 - Not Found` error.